# Installing PHP 5.4 on Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, php-5.4

So i need to install PHP 5.4 on ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64. Some other threads suggest

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install -y php5

But these do not work as the error comes on update.

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-oldstable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-oldstable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-oldstable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What is the recommended course of action for this ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824219/install-php-5-3-or-5-4-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-and-apache

Comment: When in doubt, compile from source.

Comment: Here another link you could have tried https://www.dev-metal.com/how-to-install-latest-php-5-4-x-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/

Answer (score 1):

Can you use docker for this?Another way only the compile php from sources

> docker run --name app --net mysql_net -d -p 8080:80 \   -v
>   /host/to/path/app:/var/www/app/ \   -v
>   /host/to/path/config_apache:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ \
>   romeoz/docker-apache-php:5.4

`/host/to/path/app` - path for your app and
`/host/to/path/config_apache` - path to your apache config(base file for configuration by this link https://github.com/romeOz/docker-apache-php/blob/master/5.4/configs/app.conf)

Then up container for mysql

> docker run --name db --net mysql_net -d \   -v
>   /host/to/path/data:/var/lib/mysql \    romeoz/docker-mysql:5.5

when `/host/to/path/data` - path to youre database data

Now you can use database by host `db`
App available on
http://localhost:8080