# Install php5.6 in Debian 9

Tags: php, debian, php-5.6

How to install `php5.6` in the *Debian 9*

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: libapache2-mod-php5 :
>   Depends: libdb5.1 but it is not installable Depends: libonig2 (>=
>   5.2.0) but it is not installable Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1) but it is not installable Depends: apache2-mpm-prefork but it is not
>   installable or apache2-mpm-itk but it is not installable Depends:
>   php5-cli but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct
>   problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Simple: Debian9 doesn't include php5 anymore, you cannot install it by any official means. Also this question is not really programming related, you might have more luck on [sf] or https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 98):

You can use the packages released by Ondřej Surý , see [deb.sury.org](https://deb.sury.org/)

Open the terminal and run the following command:

```
apt-get install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
```

Get the gpg key:

```
wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
```

or:

```
curl https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | apt-key add -
```

Add the new repository to your sources:

```
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
```

Install PHP5.6

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php5.6
```

To switch between PHP versions:

```
update-alternatives --config php
```

Sample output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/php7.0   70        mode automatique
  1            /usr/bin/php5.6   56        mode manuel
  2            /usr/bin/php7.0   70        mode manuel
```

Comment: @gad3r I tried your answer but now my `php-mysql` needs upgrade to and want to install `The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php7.1-common php7.1-mysql` but I dont want php7.1 also.

Comment: @Alexandros Following this answer you should have 2 php version installed on your system the `php5.6` and the `php7.X` . the `php7.1-common` is an update for the `php7.0-common` it will be installed from the debian repository . The `php5.6` will be installed from   Ondřej Surý repository . You can switch between the php versions using the `update-alternatives` command.

Comment: Fixed now! Thanks

Comment: Nice answer. To have PHP5 as apache module I had to disable php7 with `a2dismod`, then enable PHP5 with `a2enmod` then restart apache2

Comment: It still works flawlessly on 2019 :-)

Comment: The files in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ need to be readable by the user running _apt -- i.e. `chmod 0644 /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*`

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install ca-certificates apt-transport-https

wget -q https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg -O- | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list

sudo apt update
sudo apt install php5.6

sudo apt install php5.6-cli php5.6-common php5.6-curl php5.6-mbstring php5.6-mysqlnd php5.6-xml
```