# Broken dependencies while installing GD Library for php5.6 on Linode server Debian 9

Tags: linux, debian, gd, php-5.6, linode

I want to install **GD Library for php5.6 on Linode Server Debian 9**

I run `apt-get install php5.6-gd`

Output is:

```
php5.6-gd : Depends: libgd3 (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
```

then I tried to install that package `apt-get install libgd3`
output is:

```
 libgd3 : Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.11.94) but 2.11.0-6.7+b1 is to be installed
 Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not installable
```

I tried to install the mentioned version by running command `apt-get install libfontconfig1=2.11.94`

Output is:

```
Version '2.11.94' for 'libfontconfig1' was not found
```

I checked the available versions of libfontconfig1 package by running :

```
apt-cache policy libfontconfig1
```

Output is :

libfontconfig1:

```
 Installed: 2.11.0-6.7+b1
 Candidate: 2.11.0-6.7+b1
 Version table:
2.11.0-6.7+b1 500
       500 http://mirrors.linode.com/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
       100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I didn’t find the **(>= 2.11.94)** version available.

Output of **cat /etc/apt/sources.list**

```
# deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ stretch main

deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch main
```

Output of **cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/***[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NteM1.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow , please [edit here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47375168/edit)  by adding the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378017/install-php5-6-in-debian-9/46390370#46390370

Comment: This solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/47388417/6932646
is still working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On debian stretch your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list` should contain only the following line :

```
deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main
```

You need to  uncomment the above line (remove `#`) and keep the others ppa disabled (you don't need them).

The dependency problem come from the artuful ppa when enabled. To solve your problem , open the terminal then run the following command:

```
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
apt install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates curl
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
curl https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg | apt-key add -
apt update
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade
apt install php5.6
```

Use the `update-alternatives --config php` to switch between php version.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu contains conflicting version of libgd3.

```
vagrant@localhost:~$ sudo apt-cache policy libgd3
libgd3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.2.5-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     2.2.5-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     2.2.4-2+deb9u2 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
```

You need to install version from official repository like next:

```
vagrant@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install libgd3=2.2.4-2+deb9u2
```

I hope this helps.